# Is calling super always necessary when extending a View?

Tags: java, android

Is it always **a must** for extending the `View`?

```
public class MyNewView extends View{
    public MyNewView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you should. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/View.java/. Look at the source there is one non public constructor that does not take context as a arg. But that is non public. Its better to have 2 more constructors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Since `View` does not have a no-arg constructor *, derived classes must call superclass constructor explicitly.

<sup>* there is a [package-private no-arg constructor](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#3968) you cannot and should not use</sup>

Comment: One correction - it has, but it visible only inside package.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I looked at the documentation and saw it take Context as a param in the constructor but I wanted to get someone other than me to verify why it was necessary.

Comment: @Divers Yes, added that as a footnote as it's technically so but isn't relevant to OP's question.

Comment: @laalto right, just wanted to say that "does not have" not equals to "package-private".